# How to find error in large sql dump file?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm importing a large dump; command:

```
gunzip < dump.sql.gz | psql database -h localhost -U user
```

and it's hitting an error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token ""send" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ...
COPY ..., line 5210774, column ...
```

Need to debug this json, so I tried to `sed` the line

```
$ sed -n '5210774p' dump.sql
1163664 126794  89209   2017-04-09 01:33:54.889064  2017-04-09 01:33:54.889064
```

I thought `1163664` was the id, so I went back a bit

```
$ sed -n '4046110,4048110p' dump.sql > test.txt
```

It's actually just more of the same structure (looks like 3 columns and 2 timestamps)

How do I find the broken record?

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to import the dump? Add as text as update to question.

Comment: Updated with command

Comment: 1) The `...` in `COPY ...` should be the table name that the data is being copied to. That is something you can search on. 2) `line 5210774` is the line number for the row in that `COPY` data not in the file overall.

Comment: Can you show the surrounding lines for a bit of context, please?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Would it be accurate to then deduce that the line number I'm looking for is the line number where the `COPY` command began + 5210774?

Is there somewhere with more documentation about this output? A little hard to search for

Comment: 1) As mentioned before `COPY ... ` includes the table name, you can search for lines that are an offset from that. 2) You can do `pg_dump  -d <some_db> -U < some_user> ... -t <the_table> -a -f some_table_date.sql`. This will get you just the `COPY ...` for just that table and you can search for line 5210774 +-.